# npm global package installing issue

Tags: node.js, npm, vue.js, npm-install

I have faced an issue when I have tried to install Vue CLI.

windows 10,
node ~ 6.10.3
npm ~ 3.10.10

```
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'D:\Users\Subho\AppD                                                                            ata\Local\Temp\npm-9484-8858437e\registry.npmjs.org\electron-to-chromium\-\electron-to-chromium-1.3.13.tgz.111430805                                                                            1' -> 'D:\Users\Subho\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9484-8858437e\registry.npmjs.org\electron-to-chromium\-\electron-to-chr                                                                            omium-1.3.13.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"                                                                             "install" "--global" "vue-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'D:\Users\Subho\AppD                                                                            ata\Local\Temp\npm-9484-8858437e\registry.npmjs.org\electron-to-chromium\-\electron-to-chromium-1.3.13.tgz.311380074                                                                            4' -> 'D:\Users\Subho\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-9484-8858437e\registry.npmjs.org\electron-to-chromium\-\electron-to-chr                                                                            omium-1.3.13.tgz'
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js"                                                                             "install" "--global" "vue-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.10.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! tarball.destroy is not a function
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

Please help me how I fixed the issues and install the vue cli

Answer (score 2):

I removed my old node js and installed the current version 8.0.0 and my issue is solved.